# Refresh cookie by page reload

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session-cookies

My MVC3 application gets data from a COM-object via an OLE interface. For any reason, the interface does only deliver deprecated data, if the session `ASP.NET_SessionId` is active.

In my current solution I force to reset the value of the cookie `ASP.NET_SessionId` in my controller by the following function:

```
public void Refresh()
{
     Session.Abandon();
     Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""));

     Response.Redirect("~/Home");
}
```

A better solution would be a refresh by pressing F5 and reload the page in browser. But where should I use that code in my MVC3 to force that?

Comment: Please could you describe what you are actually trying to do, and why?